# What is the use of "echo || true"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Why would anyone want to have a code like `echo "something" || true` ?

I found such a usage on line 92 of `/lib/lsb/init-functions` on an Ubuntu 14.04:

`echo "$pid" || true`

I understand that || stands for OR. But I could not find a way to make echo produce any sort of exit code other than zero. And even if it does, who cares?

I mean, using the prefix `|| true` ensures that the exit code is always 0. So if the left-hand side of the double pipe yields anything different from 0, true will be executed and cause the whole line to yield 0.

Why the paranoia with the exit code of a simple echo? Is there anything checking if every single line on `/lib/lsb/init-functions` finishes with success?

Comment: Personally, by the way, I tend to write this as `||:`; slightly shorter / terser / less visually distracting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the paranoia with the exit code

I believe it is to avoid script exiting due to possible use of:

```
set -e
```

at start of the script which would have caused script to exit otherwise.

Comment: Even this requires `echo` to return a failure which I'm not sure it can really ever do, but yes, this (or over-application of a rule) seem like the two most likely "reasons".

Comment: True I can't think of a reason when `echo` will fail but this `|| true` seems to be a potential `exit` prevention.

Comment: `echo` can fail if there's an I/O error on standard output, for example if it's been redirected to a file in a nonexistent directory, or to `/dev/full`.

Comment: @KeithThompson correct for `/dev/full`. I'm not sure I understand your other argument: how can it possibly be redirected to a file in a non-existent directory?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I was thinking of `echo ... > /no/such/dir/foo.txt`, but if the output of the script is redirected that way then it won't run and the `echo` command will never be executed.

Comment: @anubhava - Good point. In this case there is no `set -e`, but since this is a function lib it is possible that the caller script uses `set -e`, so init-functions is being polite.

Comment: @KeithThompson - You are also right. It takes some invalid redirection to cause the error.

Comment: How to understand what takes place, open a shell and type the following:

`set -e; echo tras > /dev/full || true`

Now compare with the following:

`set -e; echo tras > /dev/full`

On the first example you will see an error message. On the second, the shell will close.

Comment: @Akira what do you mean by invalid redirection? be careful that when you execute: `echo 'lol' > /non/existent`, the `echo` is never executed. You get a failure return code, but that comes from Bash that can't open `/non/existent` for redirection.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, I mean, any redirection that ultimately causes an error. The point here is that echo alone does not yield anything other than zero, AFAIK (I could see its source code, but Im lazy). So the second point (after anubhava pointed the `set -e`) is how echo could possibly fail.

Comment: @Akira, in the case of `>/dev/full`, it's not the redirection that fails, but the post-redirection write. And a `1>&-` close operation will succeed, while a write() following it will fail.